# Another pattern puzzle with a twist....well, not quite so

Tags: mathematics, pattern, calculation-puzzle, sequence

What are the next two terms of the following crazy sequence:

I, h, 6, 9l, 52, 9E, 6h, __, __

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are the

> square numbers read upside-down on a calculator.

Thus, the next two terms should be

> h9 and I8, for 64 and 81 upside-down.

Comment: That's quick. Well done.